# Android Alarm Manager repeat

Tags: android

I have created app for detecting otg cable.When I launch it shows "otg not connected" and it's repeating it many times and when I plug in otg cable it's still repeating "otg not connected" and after some time it shows "otg connected" !!!!

When I start app it shouldn't show anything, it should only show when I plug in or when I plug out otg cable.And it shouldn't repeat same message many times !!!!

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Process suProcess;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getRoot();
        startAlarm();
    }

    private void getRoot()
    {
        try
        {
            suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {

        }
    }

    private void startAlarm()
    {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 1000;
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent)
    {
        File directory = new File("/sys/bus/usb/devices");
        File[] contents = directory.listFiles();

        if(contents.length == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"otg not connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"otg connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want the alarm on appstart, don't put it in the onCreate method. I would put this method in a Runnable, that regulary would call startalarm. In the AlarmReceiver class would add a static int

```
private static int conn_length = 0;
```

and in the onReceive method if would make the following code:

```
File directory = new File("/sys/bus/usb/devices");
File[] contents = directory.listFiles();

if(contents.length == conn_length){
    return;
}
else{
    conn_length = contents.length;
}

if(conn_length == 0)
{
    Toast.makeText(context,"otg not connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(context,"otg connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This way your only get a message, if the connection status changes.

Edit:

Example of a Runnable implentation.

add in the onCreate method this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(alarmUpdater);
```

and in another part of the class:

```
public Runnable alarmUpdater= new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startalarm();
    }
};
```

Comment: What is Runnable ?

Comment: How to put method inside Runnable?

Comment: It works !!! Thank you very much!!! Can you just tell me how to enable switch and disable instead of Toast in AlarmReceiver.class !!!

Comment: Where is the switch, you mean the switch as the controlelement? Ok, post the code and I give ou my two cents.